# issues with accessing the additional options from an {{action}}

Tags: ember.js

In *pre4*, I should be able to access additional parameters provided in `{{action}}`. Such as the value for **field** in this example:

```
{{action doSomething field="value" on="someEvent"}}
```

If I try and retrieve `hash.field`, nothing is returned. None of the variables that *should* contain information, do (options, contexts, hash, view).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In pre4, I should be able to access additional parameters provided in {{action}}

True in pre4 you may specify additional parameters to the `{{action}}` helper. The action helper is not expecting these parameters to be in it's options hash. Key-value pairs like `field="value` and `on="someEvent"` are interpreted as options for the action helper itself and not passed along to the target.

> If I try and retrieve hash.field, nothing is returned. None of the variables that should contain information, do (options, contexts, hash, view)

In your example above you are calling the action helper with event `doSomething` and no parameters, so it makes sense that nothing would be set. Try something like this instead:

{{action doSomething value on="someEvent"}}